# Bootstrap-ui Modal is coming up blank when set inside angular-gantt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having difficulties trying to get my modal to come up. I am not sure if it is because modal is not compatible with angular-gantt or if I have the code wrong. At the moment I get a darker screen as if there should be a modal there.

Here is the code for the button in the gantt:

JS:

```
'content':'<i class=\"fa fa-cog\" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hp_modal" ng-click="scope.show_details(task.model)"></i>' + 'Gant Object'
```

Html:

```
<div class='modal fade' id='hp_modal'>
  <div class='modal dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>This is HP modal</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is an Image of after I click on the cog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Purmp.jpg

[image]

Comment: Maybe the position of the modal is not good.
Did you tried to inspect elements in your browser?
Try to display your modal with jQuery with the same parameters in Angular. You can then check if your modal is displayed correctly.

Comment: This could be a fundamental misunderstanding on my part, but I have *never* gotten a Bootstrap modal dialog to display when it's wrapped in an element with the `modal` class applied (and here I see you are using two elements so designated). My modal templates now all start with `<div class="modal-header"></div>` and I have `modal-body` and `modal-footer` classed elements at the same level. They display fine for me <knock_on_wood />.

Comment: I have the same issue using class="modal" on top. it appears that display:hidden is not remove when modal is open... Anyone know why ? Oo

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all the class `modal` `modal-dialog` and `modal-content`
Angular already create them automaticly when you open your modal.

You just keep this tags :

> ```
>   <div class="modal-header">
>     <h5 class="modal-title">My Title</h5>
>     <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
>   </div>
>   <div  class="modal-body">
>     <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus/>
>   </div>
>   <div class="modal-footer">
>     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
>     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
>   </div>
> ```

Then if you need to use some features such as `modal-dialog-centered`, you need to use the [NgbModalOptions](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api) on open method :

> ```
>   this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(
>     this.dialogTemplateRef,
>     {centered:true}
>   );
> ```